# Google earth or some technology, create a track into GPS coordS?

Tags: html, math, google-earth

Hi there does anyone know a way, programatically or using a tool,

that I could create say a course around a Country and convert it into a series of GPS coords?

What I want to do is create a track then using the state of some unrelated data, lets say 0-100% completion, map that progression as a representation on the map.

I.E if the data is 30% completed, then represent a little running man icon on the map having walked 30% of it.

any ideas anyone? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to know how to create the data in the first place, or display it on a web page?

Comment: As @Brad insinuates you're actually asking several different questions, which doesn't work well on Stack Overflow. Break your problem down into pieces as small as you can and work on one piece at at time. When you have specific questions Stack Overflow is a good place to come, but for broad questions not so much.

Comment: Yes sorry it was a bit ambiguous! rsan has helped me out. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a track in google earth and save it as KML. KML is a DSL that most geographic viewers understand. Once you have the KML, mining this data is a different story and theres no real rule to follow. You could parse directly the kml using a XML parser and get fun with your school math and vectors or you could download a KML parser library to get quicker results.

Comment: Thanks alot! Wow looks like a bit of effort there, but its great to know its possible. Will do further research. Looks like I'll prob do as you've suggest, Create the KML track in google earth, parse the XML in my web app, then if I want to represent things visually, I'll load in google maps API and create a linestring and a marker.. lol